# why my app is not loading in browser in GKE

Tags: django, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have my deployment script running with no errors.
I have the service running with no errors.
But when I load the external IP in the browser, it loads forever with the message:
[image]
Here is my docker file:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8


EXPOSE 8080

# Install GDAL dependencies
#RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes libgdal-dev
#apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install  --reinstall -y \
  binutils \
  libproj-dev \
  libmemcached11 \
  libmemcachedutil2 \
  libmemcached-dev \
  libz-dev 

# Copy the application's requirements.txt and run pip to install all
# dependencies into the virtualenv.
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
# Add the application source code.
ADD . .

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :8080 --workers 1 --threads 8 main:app --timeout 0 --preload
```

Here is my deployment script:

```
# [START kubernetes_deployment]
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web-app
        # Replace  with your project ID or use `make template`
        image: gcr.io/app-kor/app-kubernetes:v0.0.1
        # This setting makes nodes pull the docker image every time before
        # starting the pod. This is useful when debugging, but should be turned
        # off in production.
        #imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
            - name: DB_HOST
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: DB_HOST
                  name: env
            - name: DB_NAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: DB_NAME
                  name: env
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: DB_PASSWORD
                  name: env
            - name: DB_PORT
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: DB_PORT
                  name: env
            - name: DB_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: DB_USER
                  name: env
            - name: DEBUG
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: DEBUG
                  name: env
            - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
                  name: env
            - name: INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME
                  name: env
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: POSTGRES_DB
                  name: env
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
                  name: env
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: POSTGRES_USER
                  name: env
            - name: SECRET_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: SECRET_KEY
                  name: env
            - name: SENDGRID_API_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: SENDGRID_API_KEY
                  name: env
            - name: STATIC_URL
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: STATIC_URL
                  name: env
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      # [START proxy_container]
      - image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.16
        name: cloudsql-proxy
        command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy", "--dir=/cloudsql",
                  "-instances=app:asia-northeast2:app-db=tcp:5432",
                  "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: cloudsql-oauth-credentials
            mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
            readOnly: true
          - name: ssl-certs
            mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
          - name: cloudsql
            mountPath: /cloudsql
      # [END proxy_container] 
      # [START volumes]
      volumes:
        - name: cloudsql-oauth-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: cloudsql-oauth-credentials
        - name: ssl-certs
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/ssl/certs
        - name: cloudsql
          emptyDir: {}
      # [END volumes]        
# [END kubernetes_deployment]
```

Here is my deployment service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: web
# [END service]
```

When I check the logs for of the pods, I get this:
[image]
Help: What is it then that am missing in this setup?
Logs:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `--bind 0.0.0.0:8080` in your Dockerfile? I'm thinking gunicorn is not responding to requests from the service because of the way it's configured currently.

Comment: Let me try that out @AlexWatt

Comment: @AlexWatt doesn't help. I get this ```[2020-11-12 22:12:14 +0900] [1] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2020-11-12 22:12:15 +0900] [1] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 8080)```

Comment: Hmm. Do you have any other error logs to share? In your original post there aren't any error logs, just the browser screenshot...

Comment: There are no error logs! That's the thing.

Comment: Can you deploy another deployment and try to curl from it to the original service's cluster IP? If you are able to do that, then you can be sure that the service is working but there is something wrong with your loadbalancer config. If you can't reach if from another pod, then your service yaml file has a problem.

Comment: Could you please provide information about your environment (GKE version, etc). Did you configure firewall somehow? Can you confirm that you dont have any issues inside your cluster (all pods working properly) and your LB got externalP ?

Comment: @PjoterS I can confirm all pods are running with an external IP.  GKE version: 1.16.13-gke.401. I don't think I had any firewalls setup!

Comment: Please exec into your pods and run some localhost testing this [way](https://github.com/DanyLan/GKE-EXPOSE-SERVICES/blob/master/ClusterIP.md). If you rule out issue that it is not your pod then you just need to check how your app is exposed (LB) and firewall.

Comment: Did you try what dishant makwana suggest on Nov 12 at 16:02? For example hello world. Do you have anything more on cluster like other configuration, or this is the only thing you have on your cluster?  Also did you try to change in your docker file `gunicorn --bind :8080` to `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080`